# Prevent non-integer division

Tags: c++, qt, validation

I am writing a Qt application as a hobby that prompts users to answer basic arithmetic questions using the add, minus, multiply and divide operators. The questions are generated, and everytime a question is correctly answered new operands are generated and a new operator used.

In some cases, a question might come up as '4 / 5' or '3 / 2' which implies the answer is a non-integer value to be entered. A requirement that I've set is that there are no irrational numbers in the program at all: that means no irrational answers, operands, operators or whatnot.

In my class I have a validator function which validates every question that's generated.

```
void ArQuestion::validate()
{
    int answer = getActualAnswer();

    if ((pOperand2 % 2 != 0) ||
         pOperator == operators::DIVIDE)
    {
        if (static_cast<int>(answer) != answer)
        {
            generate();
        }
    }
}
```

Where `getActualAnswer()` retrieves the actual answer of the question.

Unfortunately my validator isn't working, and presumably the `static_cast` trick isn't working either. When I run the program there are still questions that ask irrational division questions (questions which produce irrational answers). What I want the validator to do is function in a way that prevents questions (only under division questions) from asking irrationally such as '3 / 4' or '7 / 9'. If the question is irrational, then it should generate a new question.

My question is thus: what algorithm is there for me to prevent non-integer division questions from being asked?

Comment: FWIW, integer division will never produce *irrational* values (by definition).  I think you just mean "non-integer".

Comment: But your code doesn't make much sense.  You're casting `answer` to an `int`, but it's already an `int`!

Comment: Yeh, that's true; it's redundant code because it has to absolutely be an integer. I only aim to build a validator that prevents non-integer division.

Comment: Clarify what you really want to achieve.

Comment: "_...it's redundant code because it has to absolutely be an integer..._"  The type system doesn't work this way (thankfully).  `answer` is an integer, nothing anyone can do can make it anything else (without `reinterpret_cast` or similar).  Your "redundant" code does _nothing but confuse the reader_.

Comment: Prevent non-integer division. Questions like '4 / 3' or '5 / 8' produce non-integer answers: these questions are the ones that I want prevented from being asked. Questions like '6 / 3', '8 / 4' or '7 / 1' are fine because they produce integer answers.

Comment: If you want integer results, why not make the numerator some integer multiple of the denominator when they're generated.

Comment: There is a simple check.  If you calculated `answer` as `y / x`, then calculate `answer * x`.  If the result is equal to `y`, then you know it really was an integer, mathematically.

Comment: That check is apt. Though, maybe it's just chance; but now every division question generates one where both operands are equal! Indeed, I want the answer to be integer; and it's not a case that the application doesn't know what the answer is because the validation happens after questions are generated, which is a requirement too. The purpose therein is that the validator should check whether two numbers produce a non-integer answer; it the question does then it's discarded and generated again, else if the question produces an integer answer then it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly reliable,

```
bool quotient_is_integral(double n, double d)
{
    double dummy;
    return std::modf(n/d, &dummy) == 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a way to determine if a division problem returns an integer answer, here's a small function to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

bool check(double l, double r)
{
   double real_answer = l / r;
   int target_answer = static_cast<int>(real_answer);
   double checked_answer = target_answer;

   if(std::fabs(real_answer - checked_answer) > std::numeric_limits<double>::min())
   {
      std::cout << "Invalid.\n";
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will archive it as contingency.